# Importing a class' primary key in to another file's definition using Django

Tags: python, django, object

Inside views.py I have this:

```
def confirm(request):
    item = PurchaseOrder.item_number  # I want to have the primary key in here and this is wrong 
    return HttpResponse('test successful')
```

Inside models.py I have this:

```
from django.db import models

class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    item_number = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

How can I make it so that item will call the primary key of PurchaseOrder? Will I have to import files from models.py? I apologize, I am very new to Django and could not find anything on this.

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense. A primary key identifies a particular row in the database, ie a particular instance of the model. You can't just have "the primary" key in the abstract. You should do the Django tutorial (and probably a Python one if you're confused about importing), then come back and ask a specific question if you're still stuck.

Comment: I would study the tutorial a bit more, or at least provide more details of what you're trying to do.  Are you trying to look up a PurchaseOrder by a parameter passed in a `request`?

Comment: PurchaseOrder will have fields such as vendor, item, and primary key. For example: Apple, MacBook Pro, pk=1. How can I make it so that in the views.py, I can call that primary key?

Comment: Either of the answers below gives you ways to find by the primary key.  As does the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Part 3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial03/) of the tutorial goes through this, but you need a lookup:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from myapp.models import PurchaseOrder

def confirm(request, itemnum):
    item = get_object_or_404(PurchaseOrder, item_number=itemnum)
    print("Got item #: {0.item_number}".format(item)) # a test
    return HttpResponse('test successful')
```

Then in your `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from myapp import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # your other normal url patterns
    url(r'^(?P<itemnum>\d+)/$', views.confirm, name='confirm-page'),
)
```

Comment: What exactly does the last line url(r'^(?P<itemnum>\d+)/$', confirm, name='confirm-page'),
 do? Sorry, I'm still new to Django. What would I type into the URL to activate this?

Comment: @Mdjon26 Please go through the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to import your models into views.

```
from myappname.models import PurchaseOrder

def confirm(request):
  items = PurchaseOrder.objects.all()
  return HttpResponse(' '.join([i.item_number for i in items]))
```

I recommend that you go through the tutorial:
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/
It is explained how to work with the model.